# how to import schema in PySpark

Tags: python, schema, pyspark

Sorry for my stupid beginner's question.  I tried to import schema:

```
from schema import Schema
```

but I got an error: `ImportError: No module named schema`.

What do I miss here?   I am using Python 2.7.13 with Spark 2.1.0 on Windows7.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no `schema` module in PySpark.

Comment: @user281707, just check my answer let me know does it helpful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

This import("from schema import Schema") statements are importing some code from other python file.

You are doing all good but this "schema" module needs to install manually before you use in your python code.

Just run this command in cmd if you have windows platform or else on Linux you have to run it on terminal :

```
pip install schema
```

That is it !